# Laravel saving dynamic input data array in to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to save a dynamic form in laravel. unable to save data array in to data base. following is the form. 
[image]

**normal form fields in short**

```
{!! Form::select('customer_id', ['' => 'Select a customer'] + $customer_list ,null , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'customer')) !!}
{!! Form::text('mileage_in', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Mileage In']) !!}
.
.
.etc...
```

**Dynamic form fields**

```
{!! Form::select('item_id[][item_id]', $items, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
{!! Form::text('item_description[][item_description]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Not Required | Optional']) !!}
{!! Form::text('units[][units]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Add Units']) !!}
{!! Form::text('rate[][rate]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Add Rate']) !!}
{!! Form::text('amount[][amount]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Add Hrs and Rate', 'id' => 'amount']) !!}
```

all those fields are in same form.
I'm saving these data into three different tables.

following are the models i created.
**Estimate model for estimates table**

```
class Estimate extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'customer_id',
        'vehicle_id',
        'mileage_in',
        'net_amount',
        'parent_estimate_id',
        'department',
        'created_by'
    ];
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
    public function vehicle(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vehicle');
    }
    public function estimate_details(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\EstimateDetail');
    }
}
```

**EstimateDetail model for estimate_details table**

```
class EstimateDetail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'estimate_id',
        'item_id',
        'item_description',
        'units',
        'rate',
        'labor_amount_final',
        'initial_amount',
        'task_status'
    ];
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
    public function estimate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Estimate');
    }
}
```

**Item model for items table**

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'location',
        'quantity',
        'sale_price',
        'unit_of_sale',
        'pre_order_level',
        'created_by',
        'category_id',
        'service_only_cost',
        'updated_at'
    ];
    public function estimate_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EstimateDetail');
    }
}
```

Following code is the **EstimatesController**

```
class EstimatesController extends Controller
{
public function store(EstimateRequest $request)
    {
        $user_id = '1';

        $input = $request->all();

        $vehicle = new Vehicle();
        $vehicle->customer_id = $input['customer_id'];
        $vehicle->reg_no = $input['reg_no'];
        $vehicle->make = $input['make'];
        $vehicle->model = $input['model'];
        $vehicle->created_by = $user_id;

        $estimate = new Estimate();
        $estimate->customer_id = $input['customer_id'];
        $estimate->vehicle_id = $input['vehicle_id'];
        $estimate->mileage_in = $input['mileage_in'];
        $estimate->department = $input['department'];
        $estimate->created_by = $user_id;

        $estimate_detail = new EstimateDetail();
        $estimate_detail->item_id = $input['item_id'];
        $estimate_detail->item_description = $input['item_description'];
        $estimate_detail->units = $input['units'];
        $estimate_detail->rate = $input['rate'];
        $estimate_detail->initial_amount = $input['amount'];

        $vehicle->save($request->all());
        $vehicle->estimate()->save($estimate);
        $estimate->estimate_details()->save($estimate_detail);
      }
        return redirect('/estimates');
  }
```

I can successfully save vehicle and estimate data on tables vehicles and estimates. but i'm unable to save estimate details arrays on estimate_details table. tried many different ways but failed at last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess estimate id is missing. And also you cannot insert arrays like this. Try this for single item:

```
    $vehicle->save($request->all());
    $vehicle->estimate()->save($estimate);
    $estimate_detail->estimate_id = $estimate->id;
    $estimate->estimate_details()->save($estimate_detail);
```

Hope it may helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this before. but i'm getting this error. "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array"

Comment: Yes its because of you are trying to insert array at once. add an index after your items like
        $estimate_detail->item_id = $input['item_id'][0];
        $estimate_detail->item_description = $input['item_description'][0];
        $estimate_detail->units = $input['units'][0];
        $estimate_detail->rate = $input['rate'][0];
        $estimate_detail->initial_amount = $input['amount'][0];

if it works then go for a loop.

Comment: i tried adding indexes without a loop. still getting same error. "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch . . . " and detailed error as following"'insert into `estimate_details` (`estimate_id`, `item_id`, `item_description`, `units`, `rate`, `initial_amount`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (89, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Comment: Chamge your html. remove last index like

`Form::select('item_id[][item_id]'  => Form::select('item_id[]'`
`item_description[][item_description] => item_description[]`

Comment: Cheers! Now do it inside a loop without indexing.

Answer (score 0):

To store `estimate detail` in from multiple rows, You can use the following approach.

// Prepare array of all data using for loop

```
$data = [];
for($i=0,$i<count($input['item_id']);$i++)
{
 $data[]= array ('item_id'=>$input[$i]['item_id'],
                 'item_description'=>$input[$i]['item_description']);
                 'units'=>$input[$i]['units']);
                 'rate'=>$input[$i]['rate']);
                 'initial_amount'=>$input[$i]['initial_amount']);
}

Model::insert($data); // Eloquent
DB::table('table')->insert($data); // Query Builder
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i tried with both Eloquent and Query Builder "EstimateDetail::insert($data);" and "DB::table('estimate_details')->insert($data);" But i'm getting "Undefined offset: 0". any idea why this happening.

Comment: Before Insert, Please verify your `$data` array is not null and check that array creation loop.  Main think is to generate proper array from input data.